# Websphere RASWsLoggerFactory needed for Hibernate 4.3?

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, websphere

I'm trying to use Hibernate 4.3 in my existing spring 4.3 web-mvc app.

I have included the jars which are required from the distribution list. 
[image]

Beans in my application context.

```
<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource"  connection-properties-prefix="conn" properties-location="WEB-INF/orcl.properties"/> 
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

While creating the `sessionFactory`bean, the spring bean is trying to resolve `jtaplatform` and expects Websphere app server specific logger class.

But the fun part i'm running my app on tomcat, which does not have those bootstrap.jar or the classes of websphere.

My question is why do we need Websphere jars, i went inside `StandardJtaPlatformResolver`and found that the last possible(if else or a try catch method) jta provider would be websphere. 
Not sure why should i provide jta provider in this case ?

Below is the actual error out.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the culprit. Long back this app was running on websphere server, which was then migrated to jboss.

This unused
[image] jar has misled hibernate to think that there is websphere jtaplatform available.

So, removing this junk jar solved it.